# Simple Validation Formula

Tags: formula

So I'm trying to write a formula, If `Override__c` is "Yes", then  `Country__c` cannot be blank.  This is what I thought of how to do to it, but it isn't working

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Override__c, "Yes"),ISBLANK(Country__c))
```

For some reason I struggle with the syntax of formulas.. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that Override_*c is a picklist, and Country*_c is text, go with this:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Override__c, "Yes"),ISBLANK(Country__c))
```